# Contact Organizer

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, contacts

I just bought an android phone a few days ago, and I love it. There are a few things that bother me, but most of the time I find that there is a better way to manage things.

What bothers me the most at this point though is that I can't store Email addresses on the People app. I was looking for a one stop place where I'd be able to store all the information about a person including email, date of birth, profile picture etc. I'd receive reminders when their birthday comes up and stuff like that.

Is there a single app that does all that?

Comment: What kind of device is it? How are you trying to add the emails? Android's built in People app (unmodified) supports email addresses and birthdates and the like. If you add a Gmail account to a contact it will even show their Google Talk status in your contact list for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know which device you are using? But normally every Android phones People app should support the functionality of at least the basic information (meaning the emails, because it is Android ~ Google ~ Gmail). So are you really sure you can't add at least the email address to your contacts?
As mentioned already by eldarerathis, you should normally even see your contacts online status.

Maybe you can test it by logging in on your Gmail account on a pc. Add some email addresses to your contacts via the pc. Make your Android device synchronize the information you just entered (Settings > Accounts&Sync > Sync all; or something like that). Then have a look back at your People app and check if the email addresses are entered. If they are visible on your phone, that probably means that your phone supports this, but you haven't found the good way to add this information via your People app. Maybe you can search the site of the manufacturer for more information (or maybe have a look at something like a Help or Get Started app on your phone).

Comment: Well, I added my SIM from the old phone. Exported the contacts to my google account, then I'm trying to edit them by going into their profile and editing them. Can't see the email or birthday option! It's a stock android.

Comment: @AbijeetPatro: Do you have an "Add another field" button when editing them? On my Galaxy Nexus it gives me about 10 things to choose from. If not then, as mentioned previously, it may be helpful to know what *specific* kind of device it is ("a stock android" isn't really descriptive).

Comment: On my HTC One X (Sense 4+ People app), the email field is always visible when I edit a contact. Even if that contact hasn't got an email (yet)

Comment: It's not fancy shancy phone, its a local brand, one that you have probably never heard off. http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0j2xAqMqX0Y 

I remember seeing that when adding a new contact.

Comment: Yeah when adding a new contact it's there.

Comment: If it is there when you add a new contact, then it should be there when editting. Maybe under "Add fields" or something..